# How and when the loader resolves the .got table for a Linux shared library

Tags: linux, loader, elf

I want to intercept global data access, and may redirect global data access to another memory place. I think this can be done by rewriting .got entries with PIE binary. While for the shared libraries, .got resolving may be at runtime. Let’s say the sample code:

```
// main.c
int a = 0x12;
extern void foo(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("a = 0x%x\n", a); 
    foo();
    printf("a = 0x%x\n", a); 
    return 0;
}

// foo.c
extern int a;
void foo()
{
    a++;                                                                                                   
}
```

Makefile:

```
gcc -shared -fpic -Wl,-znow -g -o libfoo.so foo.c
gcc -o main main.c -Wl,-znow -g -fpie -pie -lfoo -L. -Wl,-rpath=.
```

The assembly code:

```
void foo()
{
 550:   55                      push   %ebp
 551:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 553:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   558 <foo+0x8>
 558:   58                      pop    %eax
 559:   81 c0 94 1a 00 00       add    $0x1a94,%eax
 55f:   8b 80 fc ff ff ff       mov    -0x4(%eax),%eax
        a++;
 565:   8b 08                   mov    (%eax),%ecx
 567:   81 c1 01 00 00 00       add    $0x1,%ecx
```

When the shared library wants to access the external global data, it will access through .got table. While the .got table entry is ZERO at first. So my question is how and when the loader resolves the .got table for a shared library? And if I want to intercept this, is there any way to do that? Like using LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: The answer is probably in the source code for `ltrace` http://www.ltrace.org/

Comment: Data relocations are fixed as soon as the shared object is loaded. Function relocations are the ones that can be resolved lazily.